# How can I load up jstree with inline Json?

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

Here's the jstree code:

```
 $("#tree").jstree({
          "json_data": {
              "data": treedata,
              "progressive_render": true
          },
          "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
      });
```

where `treedata` contains some Json. Unfortunately, nothing's rendering. The examples I've found are for ajax-loading the Json, but I'm proving the concept with inline Json for now. It's valid Json, but jstree isn't rendering anything at all.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

"tree" is a valid `<div>`

Comment: That jstree looks dangerous. Have you looked at spacetree implemented in Jit http://thejit.org/demos. I have ruled jstree out in my research for tree visualisation tool. Depending what you use it for, but Jit worked a treat with inline Json.

Answer (score 3):

Is your treedata json or a json string? If it's a json string you need to use `var treedata= $.parseJSON(treedatastring);` first.

I use this code in a current page and it works. I know you say your json is valid, but you might want to post it anyway or test it at this [site](http://www.jsonlint.com/)

```
var jsonConverted = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
    $('#tree').jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "data": jsonConverted
        },
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default",
            "url": "/Content/Styles/Default/themes/default/style.css",
            "dots": false
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm"]
    });
```

Where `jsonData= '[{"attr": { "id": "someid"}, "data": { "title":"SomeTitle", "icon": "/Content/images/FolderIcon.png"}, "children":[]}]';`

Be sure of your single and double quotation marks, because it makes a big difference.